# Cronjob not working on MX Linux-21

Tags: cron, d-bus, systemctl, mx-linux

I have set up a cronjob for automatic updates. However, I realized that my cronjob was not functioning. So, this is my cronjob list.

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# 
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
# 
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').
# 
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command
10 * * * * root /usr/bin/apt update -q -y >/var/log/apt/automaticupdates.log
20 * * * * root /usr/bin/apt upgrade -q -y >/var/log/apt/automaticupdates.log
25 * * * * root /usr/bin/apt-get full-upgrade -q -y >/var/log/apt/automaticupdates.log
30 * * * * root /usr/bin/apt clean >/var/log/apt/automaticupdates.log
```

But, when I run this command to enable my cronjob, it gives me some error messages which I could not diagnose properly.

```
sudo systemctl enable cron
Synchronizing state of cron.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable cron
insserv: warning: could not find all dependencies for $dbus
insserv: warning: could not find all dependencies for $dbus
insserv: warning: could not find all dependencies for $dbus
insserv: warning: could not find all dependencies for $dbus
```

However, dbus is installed in my system.

```
sudo apt install dbus
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
dbus is already the newest version (1.12.20-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Could anyone please tell me what I am missing? Or is there any error due to which cronjob is not working? Any help will be appreciated. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: You appear to be using the system-wide crontab format (with its additional user field, `root`) in a regular user crontab. See [Defining scheduled jobs with cron, 'crontab -e' vs '/etc/crontab'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/445256/defining-scheduled-jobs-with-cron-crontab-e-vs-etc-crontab)

Comment: Thanks, it worked.